# function defined as an integral involving Bessel functions

Tags: analysis, integration, asymptotics, special-functions, convex-analysis

i need to analyze a function of the form

$$F(x,y) = \int_0^{1} e^{-(1+s)\alpha x}\sinh((1-s)\beta y) I_0(\sqrt{(x^2-y^2)s}) ds $$

Where $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function.

$x>y$ always.

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ positive.

I need to explore the convexity of the function, monotony on the variables, bounds, asymptotics, some analysis on the derivatives (sign) etc.

Thanks.

Comment: *Any* own work?...

Comment: "I need this, this, this, and this" is not a very polite way to ask a question.  Perhaps you could share some of your own thoughts on the problem and give some context for why you **need** all of these things.

Comment: Is to show the convergence of a stochastic learning procedure (it needs at least 5 pages to explain).. the important part is that at one point the problem is to study the monotony, asymptotics or convexity of a function defined by $$F(x,y) = e^{-x}\int_0^{1} e^{-xu/2} \sinh(u y x/2)I_0(x\sqrt{(1-y^2)(1-u))})du$$ With $|y|<1$ and $x>0$. I tryed to use the integral form of the Bessel function (got nowhere). I also tryed changes of variable (got nowhere). now i'm trying some numerical code. In most of the scenarios it will be useful have some easy to handle form for the ratio $$I_1(x)/I_0(x)$$